# How can I determine which photo belongs to which product variation from the source code? Something is changing display to "none"

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping

**OBJECTIVE**

I am scraping a website. [This is an example of a product page](https://www.feiradamadrugadasp.com.br/corretivo-liquido-natural-beauty-jasmyne-1/p/194164/) I am having trouble with.

When one clicks on one of the variations on the right, all (or most, depending on the product) of the images on the left change. All that I need to do is **determine which photos in the gallery belong to which of the variations** from the source code.

**WHAT I MANAGED TO FIND OUT**

The image list that contains all images is located in a div of class name **"sly_carousel"**. When a click takes place, their **style="display:"** is either set to none or removed.

**PROBLEM**

I can't find where the rules that determine which images are shown/hidden on the left when an image on the right representing a variation is clicked on are located so that I can then tell which image belongs to which variation.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I inspected the code to the very best of my ability using Chrome's inspector. I found nothing either in the source or inside the little CSS window that also appears.

**PAGE LINK**

https://www.feiradamadrugadasp.com.br/corretivo-liquido-natural-beauty-jasmyne-1/p/194164/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind friend taught me it was actually done via a **post request**. Thanks anyhow!